# Split a series into two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, series

I wanted to use this `df_country` series object and divide the name of the countries in one column, and the numerical values into another column, so that it can be accessed for a bar plot.

Code:

```
df_country = df_demog_ds['Country'].value_counts().head(5)
print(df_country)
print(type(df_country))
```

Output :

```
United States     414
India             111
France             60
United Kingdom     55
Germany            50
Name: Country, dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: `df_demog_ds['Country'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Counts')` ?

Comment: I think for ploting is not necessary convert to `DataFrame`, only use `df_demog_ds['Country'].value_counts().plot.bar()`

Comment: @jezrael thank you for the solution. This is exactly what I wanted.